# Can someone give an Optimized approach?

Tags: python, optimization, code-complexity

Find distinct triplet (i,j,k) such that i<j<k and sum of the `arr[i]+arr[j]+arr[k]` is divisible by d?

If `arr = [3, 3, 4, 7, 8]` and `d = 5` it should give count as 3

- triplet with indices (1,2,3)  3+3+4=10
- triplet with indices(1,3,5)   3+4+8=15
- triplet with indices (2,3,4)  3+4+8=15

constraints

- `3<=n<=10^3`
- `1<=arr[i]<=10^9`

```
    def count_triplets(arr, d):
        n = len(arr)
        count = 0

        for i in range(n - 2):
            for j in range(i + 1, n - 1):
                for k in range(j + 1, n):
                    if (arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k]) % d == 0:
                         count += 1

        return count
```

I got this for my OA but only came up with O(n^3) approach.

Comment: Hi, could you please share your approach ? It will be easier to start from there. Also, what have you tried to make your attempt more efficient ? Keep in mind that we are not going to do the test for you, Stackoverflow is not a free coding service. In doubt, please refer to the [ask] section.

Comment: Is the code shown working or failing?  If it is working, would [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) be a better place to post this?  If the code is failing, please tell us how it is failing. Include sample input, expected output, actual output. Include error messages.

Comment: Maybe start by splitting the array in classes by same remainder modulo d?

Comment: It fails when the numbers in array are large,like arr = [10**8, 2 * 10**8, 3 * 10**8]
d= 3 * 10**8

Comment: Is there a web page with this problem? If so, can you provide link to that page?

Comment: No,It was a HackerEarth coding test

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for _narrow, specific_ questions. Requests for broad or open-ended improvements generally don't fit inside our scope (but may be better suited to [codereview.se])

Answer (score 2):

In general with questions like this, it can be helpful to sort your array so that, at each index, you can assert some statement on vast sections. Consider sorting `arr` in terms of mod d. What I mean by this is the first section of the array will constitute all numbers `x` in `arr` such that x mod d = 0.

Therefore if you take the modulus with respect to d of every value you would get something like:

`[0,...,0,1,...,1,......,d-1,...,d-1]`

Now you simply have to find 3 values which sum to 0, d or 2d. This can be done in O(n^2).

Pseudocode implementation that finds a triplet summing to d, simply set d = 2d and run this again to find a triplet summing to 2d.

```
for i in arr:
    j = i + 1
    k = arr.length() - 1
    while (j < k):
        currSum = arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k]
        if (currSum = d):
            return (i, j, k)
        else if (currSum > d):
            k--
        else j++
```

As Thierry Lathuille and anatoylg point out, this pseudocode implementation requires that you had followed the process of taking the modulus of every value resulting in the array I had displayed above. Furthermore we must only check 0, d and 2d as the largest triple sum possible is 3d-3 < 3d.

Comment: `if (currSum > d): ... ` - you missed an important thing: we are not looking for a sum equal to `d`, but for a *multiple* of d.

Comment: Fortunately, this problem is easy to fix. First check if there are 3 zeros at the beginning of the array. Then check for sum `d`. Then check for sum `2d`. Done.